# configparser, convert keys into variables

Tags: python, configparser

`hello and thanks`

i hope i am posting in the correct area

i want to convert a .ini file into local variables.
for example, let's say i have this .ini

```
[DEFAULT]
Value1=False
Value2=0
[section]
Value1=True
```

i need to create variables named

`Value1` with the value of `True`

`Value2` with the value of `0`

so i could write code like

```
if Value1==True: DoA()
if Value2==0: DoB()
```

thanks so much,
jojo

Answer (score 1):

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

variable1 = config['section']['Value1']
variable2 = config['DEFAULT']['Value2']

if variable1 == 'True':
    doA()
if variable2 == '0':
    doB()
```

Note that config keys are parsed as strings. If you need one as an integer object, use it within int()